# How to replace an array value using a condition (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays

I just want to ask how can I replace an array value if I am using a 2 dimensional array? But the hard part for me is I need to find if there's an existing ID value of the array. And that array is the one I need to replace with my new array.

Here's my code supposed that we have this ouput.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1519
            [new_lat] => 14.63807
            [new_long] => 121.03158
            [date_updated] => 2013-11-14 16:40:34
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 5413
            [new_lat] => 14.63877
            [new_long] => 121.03265
            [date_updated] => 2013-11-14 17:11:53
        )

)
```

In my PHP code I have this:

```
            //THIS IS MY NEW ARRAY
            $data_add = array( 
                'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id, 
                'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry, 
                'new_long' => $new_long_entry, 
                'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
            ); 


            //THIS WILL GET THE FILE FROM THE TXT AND MAKE IT AN ARRAY
            $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('addresses.txt'));

            //$data[] = $data_add; 

            $temp_array = array();

                    //USE THIS FOR COMPARING. THIS IS THE ID FROM MY NEW ARRAY.   
            $target = $data_add['restaurant_id'];

                    //LOOP TO SEARCH
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

                            //GET ID FROM EXISTING TXT FILE
                $get_id = $data[$i]['restaurant_id'];

                            //THEN FIND
                if($get_id == $target){

                    //if found update/delete specific row

                    //THERE'S THE PART THAT I NEED TO UPDATE

                    break;

                }else{

                    //if not found add
                    echo "not found";

                }

            }
```

That's all guys I hope you can help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$data[$i] = $data_add;
```

But I recommended you use database instead textfile

Change full code

```
//THIS IS MY NEW ARRAY
        $data_add = array( 
            'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id, 
            'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry, 
            'new_long' => $new_long_entry, 
            'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 
        ); 


        //THIS WILL GET THE FILE FROM THE TXT AND MAKE IT AN ARRAY
        $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('addresses.txt'));

        $target = $data_add['restaurant_id'];

        //LOOP TO SEARCH
        $is_new = true;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

            //GET ID FROM EXISTING TXT FILE
            $get_id = $data[$i]['restaurant_id'];

            //THEN FIND
            if($get_id == $target){
                $data[$i] = $data_add;
                $is_new = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        //IF NOT FOUND DURING CYCLE
        if ($is_new) {
               //Add new value
               $data[] = $data_add;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but I need to use textfile for some purposes.

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: You should insert this code instead //THERE'S THE PART THAT I NEED TO UPDATE

Comment: Ok but it is added also. Not updating

Comment: I think you code have one logical mistake. I rewrite your code. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may use function https://www.php.net/array_key_exists to check if key exists.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I know how to find the value. But the main problem is after finding the value I need to replace it with the new updated info.

Comment: Well, if it exists, this means that you can acess it like a regular array element. $data[$key].

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value with [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search)